# Loop through multiple databases with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to do CRUD operations on multiple databases (+20), the peculiarity is that all the databases are identical. Even some tables have the same information.

I don't want to create infinite connection strings in the json file, so I use something like this:

```
 public MyContext CreateDbContext(string db)
 {
 string? conn = config.GetConnectionString("MyConn");
 DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> builder = new();
 builder.UseSqlServer(
     $"{conn}Database={db};",
     c =>
     {
         c.MaxBatchSize(1);
         c.UseCompatibilityLevel(120);
     }
 );
 return new MyContext(builder.Options);
```

}

for example:

```
 results = new List<objet>()
 list = new string(){"db1", "db2"...}
 for each list
using MyContext ctx = CreateDbContext(db)
results.add()...
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to update d I have Concurrency and tracked conflicts.

What is the best approach for this case:?

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_, Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: For concurrency, why not just run a parallel loop? Just make sure you use a thread safe collection for your result (and any other kind of shared data structures). I'm not sure what you mean by "tracked conflicts", some SQL server specific feature?

Comment: "when I want to update d I have Concurrency and tracked conflicts." you *must* always use a single `DbContext` for a single operation and dispose it immediately, so there is no way you could get such conflicts across different contexts.

Comment: Look at [Multi-tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy)